# Jenkins - Increase number of executors for one job only

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jobs

I have a Jenkins machine with a lot of jobs running on it.
To this Jenkins, I attached 3 slave nodes.

Now, I only have one executor in the Jenkins because I don't wish to run multiple jobs simultaneously
since that can cause the jobs to fail.

BUT, I want to create just one job, that runs 3 sub-jobs simultaneously, one on every node.
I don't mind that those jobs run together, as long as any other job wont run with them as well.

If I increase the number of executors, Then other jobs that are scheduled to run at that time may enter the queue will start running.  Not good for me.

Is there a plug-in that can help my situation or any other workaround to this matter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You need a [**Build Blocker**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin) plugin. It will allow you to specify, per job, when the job should not run.

It does that with regular expressions. If jobs follow a common naming convention, you could use wildcards. Else, just list every job (that you don't want executing together) on separate lines.

There are many similar plugins, like
- [**Locks and Latches**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Locks+and+Latches+plugin)
- [**Heavy Job**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Heavy+Job+Plugin)
- [**Exclusions plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Exclusion-Plugin)

Another way is to configure a slave node, let is run on the same machine as the master, give that slave node 3 executors and configure it to run only "tied" jobs. Then, on your special job, tie it to run on that slave only.

Comment: To save you from the plugin mess the idea of using a `localhost`-slave with different labels is neat!

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the number of executors per job from this plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Heavy+Job+Plugin